# Node.js - Sending form data to hapi

Tags: html, node.js, hapi.js

I'm trying to send a variable from html form to hapi but i think i did somethings wrong.

addword.html :

```
    <form id="messages" action="/addword" method="POST">
  Your variable:
  <br>
  <input  type="text" name="your_variable" value="your_value">
  <br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

server.coffee

```
server.route
    method: 'GET'
    path: '/addword'
    handler: (request, reply) ->
        reply.file './public/addword.html'  

###
ADD WORD
###

server.route 
  method: 'POST'
  path: '/addword'
  config: payload: output: 'data'
  handler: (request, response) ->
    your_variable = request.payload.your_variable
    console.log your_variable
    return
```

/server.js

/public/addword.html

what should i change to make it work?

Comment: change `action="server.js" ` to `action="/addword" `

Comment: thanks.i did but it doesn't console at the terminal

Comment: Does the form display in your browser? What exactly is the problem?

Comment: Solved it.will write the answer later.

Comment: @Mojtaba ... still waiting?